# How can i change or edit live websites

Tags: html, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I have read about extensions which allows us to edit and make changes to live website and see how it looks. This is specifically for user interface designing. But some how i am not able to find that plugin. Can anyone tell me how i will edit a live page of anywebsite

Comment: I know about firebug and chrome devtools but i am talking about visually editing things moving divs from 1 place to another re arranging the page elements

Comment: Try the Visbug extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visbug/cdockenadnadldjbbgcallicgledbeoc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some websites designed for A/B testing that let you do this:

- https://optimizely.appspot.com/
- http://www.reedge.com/

Just enter your website URL and it will take you to a visual editor where you can modify the page with drag-and-drop.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what i am looking for can you suggest some more which are free??

Comment: I don't know off-hand but maybe you can find more by searching for A/B testing websites since that's what these sites are designed for.

Answer (score 5):

`Firebug` Addon for Firefox

`Developer Tools` in Chrome (accessed through Spanner -> Tools -> Developer Tools)

Both allow you to modify CSS and HTML content on a live webpage and instantly see the effects.

Comment: yaa but i have read somewhere about a visual editor which allows you to move divs and redesign the pages.

Comment: It's also worth listing the `Web Developer` [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) and [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) as it has some great tools that take a lot more effort using the `Firebug`/`Developer Tools`.

Comment: The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox DevTools instead, which ship with Firebug.next

Source: http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Google Chrome easily: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/  There are other options as well (Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/)

A quick crash course using Chrome:

- Ctrl + Shift + I  brings up the developer tools (or use J instead of I to go straight to the command line).  Alternatively, you can right-click anywhere on a page and click Inspect Element.
- On the right hand side you can see style information.  Uncheck boxes to disable things.  Double-click items to edit them.  The changes take place right before your eyes!
- The command line is a big help for editing/debugging javascript as well (check out the buttons at the lower left).

That should be enough to get you started.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is what you're looking for (for Firefox).

Comment: But how about if I want to integrate this into an app without using a browser extension. Is there a pluging or an app that can do that ?